# How to set a value explicitly into a http uri in Query parameter

Tags: spring, http, apache-camel

.to("http4://oldhost?order=123&detail=short");
Consider this as my end point and I need to get from message and set value in query parameter (detail) instead of directly passing a value as short I need to call a method, is it possible?

from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("order=123&detail=${body.getDetail()}"))
.to("http4://oldhost");
I want something like this but its not working.

Comment: I guess that you would like to add a dynamic query parameter into your url?  why not get the data from other api and then use a temp variable  replace ```${body.getDetail()}``` ?   Except this,  I have not see the usage  which use $ to get the value from uri before .